# Access element in array(array(array(...)))

Tags: php

I am having the following array with test data:

```
'team' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'adfadsf',
      'lastName' => 'asdfadsfa',
      'twitter' => 'ddasfasdf',
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'adf',
      'lastName' => 'asd',
      'twitter' => 'www.twitter.com/dfs',
    ),
    2 => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'asd',
      'lastName' => 'adf',
      'twitter' => 'www.twitter.com/adf',
    ),
    3 => 
    array (
      'firstName' => 'test',
      'lastName' => 'test',
      'twitter' => 'www.twitter.com/test',
    ),
  ),
```

I would like to access the attributes `firstName` and `lastName`.

I tried the following, where $request has as one attribute the `team` array:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
    Log::info($key);            

    $team = new Team();
    $team->firstname = $request->team[$key]['firstName'];
    $team->lastname = $request->team[$key]['lastName'];
    $team->twitter = $request->team[$key]['twitter'];
    $team->revisions_id = $revision->id;

    Log::info("team");            
    Log::info($team);

    $team->save();
}
```

Any suggestions how to access the two attributes `firstName` and `lastName`?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Please extract a minimal example. Here, the loop is redundant, but the way your data structures look is still not really clear.

Comment: you are iterating over $request, so the first and only item will be "team". You will need to loop through that (afterwards)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking to your data sample 
you should iterate over $request['team']  and accessing to $value for obtain  firstName and lastname....

```
foreach ($request['team'] as $key => $value) {
    Log::info($key);            

    $team = new Team();
    $team->firstname = $value['firstName'];
    $team->lastname =  $value['lastName'];
    $team->twitter =  $value['twitter'];
    $team->revisions_id = $revision->id;

    Log::info("team");            
    Log::info($team);

    $team->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is not completely clear what's in `$request`, but I suggest this:

```
foreach ($request as $key => $value) {
    Log::info($key);            
    if ($key == 'team') {
        foreach ($value as $ar_team) {
            $team = new Team();
            $team->firstname = $ar_team['firstName'];
            $team->lastname = $ar_team['lastName'];
            $team->twitter = $ar_team['twitter'];
            $team->revisions_id = $revision->id;
            Log::info("team");            
            Log::info($team);

            $team->save();
        }    
    }
}
```

Or simply (if other items in `$request` are **not** used in `foreach`):

```
foreach ($request['team'] as $ar_team) {
    $team = new Team();
    $team->firstname = $ar_team['firstName'];
    $team->lastname = $ar_team['lastName'];
    $team->twitter = $ar_team['twitter'];
    $team->revisions_id = $revision->id;
    Log::info("team");            
    Log::info($team);

    $team->save();
}
```